# jQuery create an expandable unordered list with ul li with extra span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create an expandable tree with unordered list. The deepness is not limited in my case.
I have to keep the text in the list elements as it is, this way I need to add an extra span element to every parent to have a clickable item.

I have tried to add this span tag with jQuery, and this finds the li objects, but in the result only the first occurrance is visible.

The HTML code is this.

```
<ul class="list">
<li>
  Categories
  <ul>
      <li>
        Parent
        <ul>
          <li><a href="page.html#11">link 1</a> <a href="page.html#12">link 2</a> <a href="page.html#13">link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="page.html#21">link 1</a> <a href="page.html#22">link 2</a> <a href="page.html#23">link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>  
      <li>
        Parent
        <ul>
          <li><a>Child 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Child 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Child 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>  
  </ul>                
</li>
</ul>
```

My jQuery script is below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".list").each(function () {
        $(this).find('li').each(function(index, element){
            var text = $(this).html();
            text = "<span class=\"trigger\">+</span> " + text;
            $(element).html(text);
        });
    });

    $('.list > li span').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().children('ul').toggle();
        if($(this).text() == '+') {
            $(this).text('-');
        }
        else {
            $(this).text('+');
        }
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pegapega/2f20s90v/

My expected result would be for every li element:

```
<li><span class="trigger">+</span>[original content]</li>
```

Why the span element is not added to all of the li elements?

Comment: specifically I'm not sure the reason something to do with dom traversal, but the example can be fixed by putting another each loop inside

Comment: I was thinking about a recursive function, but couldn't solve that yet. But if I put an alert(text); after modifying the text variable, I can see all the li elements, but it is not appearing in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure exactly why your code example didn't work, but here is an example that does work based on you original.

```js
    $('li').each(function(i, e){
      $(e).prepend('<span class="trigger">+</span>');
    });
 
    $('span').on('click', function(e){
        $(e.target).next('ul').toggleClass('show');
        if( $(e.target).text() == '+') {
         $(e.target).text('-');
        } else {
         $(e.target).text('+');
        }
    });
```

```css
span.trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul {
 display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
ul.show {
  display: block;
}

ul.list {
 display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
 <li>
   Root
   <ul>
    <li>
   Parent
   <ul>
     <li><a href="page.html#11">link 1</a> <a href="page.html#12">link 2</a> <a href="page.html#13">link 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="page.html#21">link 1</a> <a href="page.html#22">link 2</a> <a href="page.html#23">link 3</a></li>
   </ul>
    </li>  
    <li>
   Parent
   <ul>
     <li><a>Child 1</a></li>
     <li><a>Child 2</a></li>
     <li><a>Child 3</a></li>
   </ul>
    </li>  
   </ul>                
 </li>
</ul>
```

Stackoverflows snippet editor seemed to have some problem with toggle() so I just replaced it with toggleClass() just so the example would work.

Comment: Thanks, this prepend works fine. I have updated my jsfiddle with your code, and a bit extra to check if there are any chilid ul element. https://jsfiddle.net/pegapega/efp4n7qj/4/